# Find matching pairs of elements in two vectors (different lengths) of user defined type based on similarity metric

Tags: c++

I have two std::vector< Point >, PV1 and PV2, which can contain a different number of elements and a similarity metric function between two Point, A and B, lets say

double simMetric(Point a, Point b)

I am looking for the most efficient way to calculate the set of matching pairs, where a match is defined as there exists a point P1 in PV1 and a point P2 in PV2 whose similarity metric is the minimum between all pairs in PV1 and PV2 and below a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to solve the [Minimum-Cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). There are several linear programming solutions to this problem. Though all of them require that you calculate the similarity for all connections between both lists.

Though depending on your point set and similarity function faster options may exist.